# c++: declspec, static libraries and DLLs

Tags: c++, dll, static

I have some 3rd party open source code that was previously released/compiled as a DLL, that I want to re-compile as a static library for inclusion in my project.

When compiling the 3rd party code as a static library, the .lib file gets built without error, but when including it in my project, I get "unresolved external" errors for virtually every reference to the functions in that static library. These errors did not occur when the library was compiled as a DLL.

The errors seem related to LNK4217 and LNK4049 warnings I get during the build phase of my project, which seem to be related to the fact that most of the functions in the 3rd part library's headers are tagged with __declspec(dllexport).

My guess is that 'dllexport' is tagging those functions as being DLL-specific, so they're getting skipped when the library is built statically. How can I get those functions to be included in the static version of the library?

Comment: See how to build and link static .lib

Comment: dllexport makes the name an exported object of the dll. When it is dynamically loaded this name must match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually something like an `API` macro will exist for this purpose. It occurs in the API header and looks like this...

```
// If we are Microsoft C/C++ Compiler
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
    #if defined(DLL_EXPORT)
        #define API __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif

// If we are non Windows (Export by default) or compiling to a StaticLibrary
#else
    #define API 
#endif
```

All API functions would then have the `API` macro in the declaration instead of the raw `__declspec(dllexport)`

The next step is in the various build configurations in Visual Studio you can define `DLL_EXPORT` as a preprocessor directive if the configuration is targeting a DynamicLibrary (DLL) in `Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Definitions`.

An example...

```
DLL_EXPORT;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)
```

You can also check the public symbols by running

```
dumpbin /LINKERMEMBER thing.lib
```

from the *Developer Command Prompt*.

Comment: Nice platform independent methodology.

Comment: Thank you, I followed your advice and everything works great :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VS to re-compile 3rd party code as static library then it would be better to create a new project. Please note that `static library` needs different settings all together.

The option to create `static library` application type is available under `Win 32` templates. You can choose either `Win32 Console` or `Win32 Projet` as an option. Once you have crated the project then you can include code from 3rd party in you new project and compile.

If any of class definitions have used `__declspec(dllexport)` then it should be replaced with `API` or just don't use any macros. This is needed because functions are not exported functions from `static library` rather those get embedded in application adding reference to `static library`. You can then try to build `static library`.

Add reference to this newly build static library in your application project and build it.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep it as a dll. You are waisting your time doing this and doesn't make sense.

That said there is a second level of strangeness, in that you can use functions from dlls exactly like a static library. So they get pasred into your source at build time and they don't require you attatch the entire dll to the completed build in order to execute. Just like a static lib the parts you used are linked in, also it could give a slight performance gain because it doesn't have to load them at run time during the start of the program. It would be exactly the same as if you used a static library (actually you are, that's why there is a MyDll.lib with MyDll.dll). So your not even reducing the final binaries size or anything. Now consider the benefits of the dll. It's simple to update funtionslity, simply copy new dll (like if improvent is made to your open source api you are using) into directory or where ever your code expects it and that's it. You can even load the dll at run time and check versioning etc and handle version mismatches and other issues gracefully.

Comment: I appreciate the advice, but this doesn't help me. I want to compile statically for the sole purpose of not having to bundle extra DLLs with my code (unless I'm misunderstanding what you're saying).

Comment: You can force inline the imported function. This would not require the dll.